How to Solve a DAE System with Integral Constraint and Moving Boundary in Mathematica?
I am currently working on solving a DAE system in Mathematica, which includes an integral constraint and a moving boundary. I have attempted to use ParametricNDSolve, but it doesn't seem to work for my problem. Actually it origins from a research article(https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2013.0066). For simplicity, here are the details:

If I ignore the constraint, simply let D=1 (Dw in my code), then I could get a solution directly from NDSolve:
\[Gamma]w = 1; \[Theta]G = 
 Pi/6; Dw = 1; eqs = {x'[s] == Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
  y'[s] == Sin[\[Theta][s]], \[Theta]''[s] == 
   nx[s]*Sin[\[Theta][s]] - ny[s]*Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
  nx'[s] == -(\[Gamma]w/(r[s]))*Sin[\[Theta][s]], 
  ny'[s] == (\[Gamma]w/(r[s]))*Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
  r'[s] == 0, \[Beta]'[s] == 0}; bc0 = {x[0] == 0, 
  y[0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0}; bc1 = {x[Dw] == 
   r[Dw]*Sin[\[Beta][Dw]], \[Theta]'[Dw] == 0, 
  nx[Dw] == -\[Gamma]w*Cos[\[Beta][Dw]], 
  ny[Dw] == \[Gamma]w*
    Sin[\[Beta][Dw]], \[Theta][Dw] + \[Beta][
     Dw] == \[Theta]G}; var = {x, y, \[Theta], nx, ny, 
  r, \[Beta]}; sol = NDSolve[Join[eqs, bc0, bc1], var, {s, 0, Dw}]

Next, I can find out appropriate D to fit with the constraint through changing the variable and repeating the calculation. However, such method seems inefficient.
I am wodering if there exists any direct methods to deal with such system. I tried ParametricNDSolve, however, I found it seems can't work because the position of D.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!

To compute constraint, we can use code as it is with a small modification as follows
int[Dw_?NumericQ, tension_, wetting_] := 
  Module[{\[Gamma]w = tension, \[Theta]G = wetting}, 
   eqs = {x'[s] == Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
     y'[s] == Sin[\[Theta][s]], \[Theta]''[s] == 
      nx[s]*Sin[\[Theta][s]] - ny[s]*Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
     nx'[s] == -(\[Gamma]w/(r[s]))*Sin[\[Theta][s]], 
     ny'[s] == (\[Gamma]w/(r[s]))*Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
     r'[s] == 0, \[Beta]'[s] == 0}; 
   bc0 = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0}; 
   bc1 = {x[Dw] == r[Dw]*Sin[\[Beta][Dw]], \[Theta]'[Dw] == 0, 
     nx[Dw] == -\[Gamma]w*Cos[\[Beta][Dw]], 
     ny[Dw] == \[Gamma]w*
       Sin[\[Beta][Dw]], \[Theta][Dw] + \[Beta][Dw] == \[Theta]G}; 
   var = {x, y, \[Theta], nx, ny, r, \[Beta]}; 
   sol2 = NDSolve[Join[eqs, bc0, bc1], var, {s, 0, Dw}]; 
   ind = Quiet@
     NIntegrate[y[s] Cos[\[Theta][s]] /. sol2[[1]], {s, 0, Dw}, 
      Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 5]; (-1 + 
      r[Dw]^2 (\[Beta][Dw] - 1/2 Sin[2 \[Beta][Dw]]) + 
      2 x[Dw] y[Dw] - 2 ind ) /. sol2[[1]]];

Using ContourPlot we can solve equation for constraint as
 plot=ContourPlot[int[q1, q2, Pi/2] == 0, {q1, .8, 1.255}, {q2, .1,2.5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Dw", "\[Gamma]w"}] 


We can retrieve roots from plot in a form of list
roots=plot[[1]][[1]][[1]];

Finally, we can compute solution for every pare of parameters in the roots
sol[Dw_?NumericQ, tension_, wetting_] := 
  Module[{\[Gamma]w = tension, \[Theta]G = wetting}, 
   eqs = {x'[s] == Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
     y'[s] == Sin[\[Theta][s]], \[Theta]''[s] == 
      nx[s]*Sin[\[Theta][s]] - ny[s]*Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
     nx'[s] == -(\[Gamma]w/(r[s]))*Sin[\[Theta][s]], 
     ny'[s] == (\[Gamma]w/(r[s]))*Cos[\[Theta][s]], 
     r'[s] == 0, \[Beta]'[s] == 0}; 
   bc0 = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0}; 
   bc1 = {x[Dw] == r[Dw]*Sin[\[Beta][Dw]], \[Theta]'[Dw] == 0, 
     nx[Dw] == -\[Gamma]w*Cos[\[Beta][Dw]], 
     ny[Dw] == \[Gamma]w*
       Sin[\[Beta][Dw]], \[Theta][Dw] + \[Beta][Dw] == \[Theta]G}; 
   var = {x, y, \[Theta], nx, ny, r, \[Beta]}; 
   sol2 = NDSolve[Join[eqs, bc0, bc1], var, {s, 0, Dw}]; sol2[[1]]];


solr = (sol[#[[1]], #[[2]], Pi/2] & /@ roots) // 
    Quiet; 

Visualization function $\theta (Dw)$ dependent on $\gamma w$
listtetD = 
 Table[Quiet@
   Evaluate[{roots[[i, 2]], \[Theta][roots[[i, 1]]] /. 
      solr[[i]]}], {i, Length[roots]}];
ListLinePlot[listtetD, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"A\[Gamma]w/(YI)", "\[Theta](Dw)"}]


As we can see this is one curve shown in Figure 3 in the paper computed for the wetting angle $\theta_{\gamma}=\pi /2$.

I appreciate the time and effort you put into explaining the steps and providing a clear example. Your expertise has been incredibly helpful, and I am grateful for your assistance.

@Mikoto You are welcome!
